# Can't load python NMSLIB index?

Tags: python-3.x, information-retrieval

I'm trying to load an index of about 8.6GB using [nmslib](https://pypi.org/project/nmslib/) by the following commands:

```
search_index = nmslib.init(method='hnsw', space='cosinesimil')
search_index.loadIndex('./data/search/search_index.nmslib')
```

But, the following error happens:

```
Check failed: data_level0_memory_
Traceback (most recent call last):
search_index.loadIndex("./data/search/search_index.nmslib")
RuntimeError: Check failed: it's either a bug or inconsistent data!
```

My computer has only 8GB as primary memory. So, did this error happen because the index is over 8GB and could not be loaded into memory?

Thank you for any help.